# Generate Fibonacci sequence via matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I saw some code to generate the $N^{th}$ Fibonacci number in $O(\log_{2}N)$ time, but I don't understand why the math works.

The code first initalizes two matrices:
$$
A =\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
, \qquad B =\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It then iterates over the bits of $N$ starting from the least significant bit.  For each bit of the number $N$, two things happen:

1. If the bit is $1$, then $B = B * A$
2. Then $A = A * A$ either way

After that, the $N^{th}$ fibonacci number will be in $B_{0,0}$.

Why does this work?

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed. This is very much an "I am wondering *this*" kind of question, which I think we should encourage more of. (That said, the question would benefit from a reference to where the code was found.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know that

$$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$ and this method computes the powers of $A$.

Now, you can re-generate and integer $n$ from its bits $b_k$, from most significant to least significant, by the recurrence

$$m_{-1}=0,\\m_k=2m_{k-1}+b_k.$$

Following this scheme, you obtain the powers $X^{m_k}$ of a matrix $X$ by

$$M_{-1}=M^0=I,\\M_k=X^{2m_{k-1}+b_k}=M_{k-1}^2X^{b_k}$$ where $X^{b_k}$ is either $I$ or $X$.

Comment: Thanks!  I have a couple more questions though.  What is $F_n$ ?  And why do we need the powers $X^{m_k}$ of X?

Comment: @AzeezahM: lookup the Wikipedia entry.